# How to add custom extension to existing vm using arm template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

How to add the following  custom extension to run the powershell script in already existing  VM ? How to refer to existing VM ?

```
{
"condition":"[empty(parameters ('DR User Secret'))]",
"type":"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
"name":"[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/', 'customscript')]",
"apiVersion":"2015-06-15",
"location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
"properties":{
   "publisher":"Microsoft.Compute",
   "type":"CustomScriptExtension",
   "typeHandlerVersion":"1.9",
   "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
   "settings":{
      "fileUris":[

      ]
   },
   "protectedSettings":{
      "commandToExecute":"[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file ', 'C:\\test.ps1', ' -AdminPass ', parameters('Password'))]"
   }
}
```

}

Comment: the param `parameters('vmName')` refers to your vm ?

Comment: Your template should work fine, if the vm exists in the same resource group to which you deploy the customScript extension.  What errors do you see when you attempt the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way you may also try.
I created a VM using the ARM template.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template

[image]

And I use the below following command that uses the Custom Script extension to download a script from a GitHub repository onto the target virtual machine and then run the script.

**fileUris: The locations where the script files are stored.**

> Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName "v-rash18" `-VMName "SampleVM" -Name "myCustomScript"`
> -FileUri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neilpeterson/nepeters-azure-templates/master/windows-custom-script-simple/support-scripts/Create-File.ps1"
> `
> -Run "Create-File.ps1" -Location "Central US".

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/features-windows#run-vm-extensions

To check the extension is set on the existing VM is **Get-AzVMExtension**
[image]